# Custom listview item xml disabling onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, xml, listview, onitemclicklistener

i am using below xml for my ListView item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feel The Light" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home" />



</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user_audio_call_dark"
            android:id="@+id/btn_audio_call"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user_video_call_dark"
            android:id="@+id/btn_video_call"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Invite"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_green_oval"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/btn_invite"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i know in this xml some views are overlapping each other but in my custom array adapter i make visibility to gone for some of them based on certain condition, but what this xml do is to disable my ListView onItemClickListener but if i exclude this from xml then onItemClickListener works fine but i want to make onItemClickListener work without removing xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user_audio_call_dark"
            android:id="@+id/btn_audio_call"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user_video_call_dark"
            android:id="@+id/btn_video_call"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Invite"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_green_oval"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/btn_invite"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "make onItemClickListener with removing xml" what is removing xml?

Comment: i want to make onItemClickListener work without removing xml

Comment: @user7661245: try my below solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter `getView()`, set `onClickListener` to each button.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Do something
        }
}
```

If you want to handle `click` event for entire list item then you need to set `onClickListener` to root `LinearLayout` of your `listViewItem` XML:

**ListViewItem XML:** Give an `id` to `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="16dp"
android:id="@+id/container">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

.................
...................
```

**Adapter:** Set `OnClickListener` to `LinearLayout`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    .............
    .................
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

    container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Do something
        }
    }
    .................
    ...................
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: @user7661245; If my answer helps you then please accept with giving upvote. Thank you :)

Comment: @user7661245 if my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance